# how do I implement payable in erc1155?

Tags: solidity, ether, javascript, etherscan, ethers.js

I'm so new to solidity and I'm trying to implement payable Nft using ethers.js. I think I'm checking the balance of the address and comparing it with mintRate * amount wrong. I tried something like this require(msg.value >= mintRate * amount,"not enough ether") but it kept on throwing me the "not enough ether" error although I have enough. The mintRate is 0.0001 eth. but I have like 1.1177 eth. I don't know why I'm getting this error. kindly help me figure this out. thanks in advance

Solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";

contract MintNFT_ERC1155 is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Supply {
    uint256 public mintRate = 0.0001 ether;

    constructor() ERC1155("") {}


    function mint(
        address account,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        string memory uri
    ) public payable {
        require(address(this).balance >= mintRate * amount, "not enough ether sent");
        _mint(account, id, amount, "");
        _setURI(uri);
    }

    function mintBatch(
        address to,
        uint256[] memory ids,
        uint256[] memory amounts
    ) public payable {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, "");
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address operator,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256[] memory ids,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal override(ERC1155, ERC1155Supply) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```

js :

```
require("dotenv").config()
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL
const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3")
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL)
const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/MintNFT_ERC1155.sol/MintNFT_ERC1155.json")
console.log(JSON.stringify(contract.abi))
const contractAddress = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress)

mintNFT("ipfs://xxxxxxxxxx",1, 3,)
async function mintNFT(tokenUri, id, amount) {
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, 'latest'); //get latest nonce

  //the transaction
    const tx = {
      'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
      'to': contractAddress,
      'nonce': nonce,
      'gas': 300000,
      'data': nftContract.methods.mint(PUBLIC_KEY,id, amount,tokenUri).encodeABI()
    };

    console.log(tx);
    

    const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
  signPromise
    .then((signedTx) => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTx.rawTransaction,
        function (err, hash) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(
              "The hash of your transaction is: ",
              hash,
              "\nCheck Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
            )
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Something went wrong when submitting your transaction:",
              err
            )
          }
        }
      )
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(" Promise failed:", err)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code declares that the contract `MintNft` itself has to have `mintRate * amount` ETH. Instead, your require statement should read:

```
    `require(msg.sender.balance >= mintRate * amount, "not enough ether sent");`
```

...you needn't use msg.value here, because the `_mint` function of ERC1155 checks for sufficient balance effectively whilst undertaking the mint.

It's worth noting that `msg.sender.balance` is returned in Wei (1 Wei = 1e-18 ETH), so although your `require` should pass, you might want to modify it since you evaluate `mintRate * amount` in ETH.

also, `'not enough ether sent'` is kinda ambiguous/misleading. Perhaps `"you don't have enough ether to perform this transaction"` is better

Comment: thank you so much. It works now :)